OCR From <input type="file">
What I want to do is use
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpe,image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp">

To use the camera from the device or select some picture/image, happens when this happens automatically apply OCR and extract the text from the picture/image and put this text on a <input type="text">.
Is this possible to use just JavaScript or some library.js? I know that it is possible to use back end technology, but if it is possible to do this on the front end with JS that would be perfect.
EDIT: As @ctrlshifti said in the comments i try to use Tessereact.js but gives me this error:

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level
bodies of modules

This is my code:
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    const fileF = document.getElementById('fileF'),
        txtF = document.getElementById('txtF');

    const worker = await Tessereact.createWorker();
    await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
    await worker.initialize('eng');

    fileF.onchange = async => {
        const res = await worker.recognize(fileF.files[0]);// On this line shows the error
        txtF.value = res.data.text;
    };
});

But that await is inside of an async function.
EDIT 2: If someone helps this is what i do in a very basic way but functional and simple:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>OCR Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tesseract.js/5.1.1/tesseract.min.js" integrity="sha512-mpQLT7yiRJ06RkhNTYhVnvvr3c71il3h+wEI16ICc+fnFHxrBRoJrMmDJ8iBY04+U/FgTj7xah5Vbltq5pg+aQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            const fileF = document.getElementById('fileF');
            Tesseract.recognize(
                fileF.files[0],
                'eng',
            ).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
                document.getElementById('textF').value = text;
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
    <input type="file" id="fileF" accept="Image/jpg, image/gif, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="myFunction()">
    <input type="text" id="textF">
</html>


As far I know you can use OCR on client-side using Tesseract.js

Your Edit #2 works for me. What issue are you still having?

i have not issue now, the edit 2 it's what i want to do at first :)
